# What is the correct way of determining Routes in React ?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I couldn't understand the theoretical part of choosing routes. There are many examples out there which implements routes like /authentication /user:id but how can we decide which routes we need in our application. I am not able to distinguish do I have to use route for something or not.

Comment: If you want the ability to navigate your site using the address bar use routes. Otherwise, it doesn't really matter. Routes are good for organizing larger web applications. It also allows you to copy+paste a link and direct the user appropriately.

Comment: The same way you determine the routes for any web application.

Answer (score 1):

"how can we decide which routes we need in our application"

Routes are entry points into your application. Anything the user types in manually in the address bar, copy-pastes from somewhere, clicks on a link in an email, etc. can be an entry point.

So whenever you have an entry point (page loading for the first time) that is NOT simply the default route or default page loading behavior, you need a new route.

For single page apps, this usually boils down to looking at the URL with JS code at runtime and deciding which view/component to render. Most projects rely on libraries like react-router to formalize and automate this functionality.